# Binding to indexed property with String key

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, dictionary, idictionary

Say I wanna bind to dictionary that TKey is string with XAML:

```
<Label DataContext="{MyDictionary}" Content="{Binding Item("OK")}" />
```

Doesn't work.

How should I do it?

I am talking about the Item("Key")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try that :

```
<Label DataContext="{Binding MyDictionary}" Content="{Binding [OK]}" />
```

Or that (a bit simpler) :

```
<Label Content="{Binding MyDictionary[OK]}" />
```

Comment: well, I knew it was possible with list indexes, I wasn't sure about dictionary keys.. I just tried, and it worked ;)

Comment: For me, the first suggestion does [not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623728/using-hashtable-as-datacontext-for-wpf-xaml-binding#comment20428624_14623728).

Comment: This does not work when the key has spaces or other special characters like periods and slashes, though. I tried putting the key into double and single quotes but neither works.