# Using Hashtable as DataContext (for WPF/XAML Binding)

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, hashtable, datacontext

In code I have a Hashtable named `MyHashtable`. This Hashtable contains an element with key=`"Value"`, value=`3`. I'm currently trying to bind this value to a textbox. This is my XAML code:

```
<TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding MyHashtable[Value]}" />
<TextBlock Margin="4" DataContext="{Binding MyHashtable}" Text="{Binding [Value]}" />
```

**Q:** Why does the second binding not work, while the first binding works just great?

For the second binding I have tried other bindings for the text, such as: `Value`, `this[Value]` or even `Me[Value]`, but they all did not work.

---

Using `Item[Value]` gives me an interesting exception: `Parameter count mismatch.`
<strike>Does somebody understand this?</strike> This is because of differences between C# and VB.NET. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642503/binding-to-multiple-indexed-properties-in-net).

Comment: Try DataContext[Value] for the second binding.

Comment: I thought the point of DataContext was that you don't need to refer to `MyHashtable` in any further bindings? Anyway, I tried it and it did not work either.

Comment: The error is saying that it did not find property "Item" in the Hashtable type, which is true.

Comment: trye specifying Text="{Binding Path=[Value]}. If it does not work hardcode Value with a known existing value just for the sake of debugging

Comment: @LuisFilipe, tell me, why does it not find [Hashtable.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.item.aspx)? And believe me, I'm testing all possible scenarios against hardcoded values. :) By the way, adding `Path=` will not make any difference usually.

Comment: @RuudLenders Inspecting hashtable's metadata there is no Item property. The link you provided refers that it is an indexed property.

Comment: i was just reading this link,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx

Comment: @LuisFilipe, I've tried `Path=` anyway, and it did not change anything. I believe indexed properties do not work well with WPF bindings.

Comment: @LuisFilipe, I found out why there is no metadata of the Item property. It's because of differences between VB.NET and C#. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642503/binding-to-multiple-indexed-properties-in-net). But even without the Item property, there should be some way to use `DataContext` here...

Comment: I've checked it, and the second binding works in VS Express 2012 (as it should).
Try using Dictionary if you have problems on your version.

Answer (score 1):

For second option you can just use this:

```xaml
<TextBlock Margin="4" 
     DataContext="{Binding MyHashtable}" 
     Text="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
            Path=DataContext[Value]}" />
```