# Binding to multiple indexed properties in .NET?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

Binding to this property is fairly simple:

```
public Foo MyFoo {get; set;}

public class Foo
{
    public object this[object key]
}
```

Because here in XAML you can do:

```
<Label Content="{Binding MyFoo["key"]}"/>
```

But what if I had a second indexed property?

I know this is not directly possible in C#, but in VB.NET it is.

```
Default Public Property Item(key As Object) As Object 'equivalent to this[...]'
Public Property Item2(key As Object) As Object 'a second indexed property!'
```

These are some of the bindings I've tried:

```
<Label Content="{Binding MyFoo["key"]}"/>
<Label Content="{Binding MyFoo.Item["key"]}"/>
<Label Content="{Binding MyFoo.Item2["key"]}"/>
```

The first binding will still work, but the other two won't.

Is there a direct solution to this, or do I need a workaround?

Comment: If you have that class in an assembly and reference it in a C# project, how would code look like to access the two indexed properties? Because if it´s possible in VB, it means it´s somehow reflected in the MSIL and therefore has to be accessible from C#. Never seen it before.

Comment: @Jobo, thanks for that smart idea. It led me to an answer that I'm OK with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [Jobo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1041340/jobo)'s suggestion to place the VB.NET class in an assembly, and reference to it in a **C#** project,
I found out why you can't *directly* bind to multiple indexed properties.

Under the hood, two methods are generated for every *extra* indexed property: `get_X` and `set_X`, where `X` is the name of the indexed property.

This means that the VB.NET indexed properties, that are not marked as `Default`, actually **don't exist**. This is why the XAML bindings in my question said that it could not find properties `Item` or `Item2`...

Probably, there are multiple workarounds for this problem. You could, for example, create a small class that contains an indexer property, and then have multiple instances of that class in your `MainWindow`.

Another workaround could be binding to the return value of `get_X`, but I could only imagine how irritating this would get, since this way you won't get the benefits of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.